# Как можно проверить строки, хранящиеся в char* на полную идентичность?

Tags: c, алгоритм, строки, указатели, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм LZW на C. значения слов храню в `char*`, а само слово - структура.

```
typedef struct Word {

unsigned int code; 
char * value; 
} Word;
```

Словарь организовал так

```
 Word * dictionary [4096];
```

Есть еще текущее слово

```
Word prefix;
```

Правда ли, что этим кодом:

```
if (prefix.value == dictionary[i]->value){
            prefix.code = dictionary[i]->code;
            // Выходим из цикла проверки, возвращаемся к основному циклу 
            break;          
        }
    }
```

Я сравниваю два указателя? То есть два адреса в памяти, которые понятное дело не равны? Правильно ли я определил ошибку? Если это так, то как можно проверить на равенство те значения, которые находятся в `char*`?

Для тех, кому нужен полный код, прошу пройти к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133650/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-lzw-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правда, сравниваете два указателя.

Для сравнения C-style строк применяются функции типа [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), `strncmp` и т.п. (см. по указанной ссылке внизу страницы).

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: memcmp ещё когда строки это не совсем строки